# How to get access token, refresh token in .NET Core (C#) without using SDK (Manually) in QuickBooks Online API?

Tags: c#, access-token, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have created a simple console app in C#, I need to request access token without using SDK. I have managed to launch a URL to request code. I get code but trying to call the access_token endpoint is a challenge. I need help on how I can get access_token and refresh_token. Attached is the screenshot of codes having all the request details and the endpoint I used as follows.

Endpoint used: https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer

Parameters: code,=[codeReceived] grant_type = authorization_code and redirect_uri = [RedirectUrl]

Headers:Authorization: Basic [Base64EncodedBytes], Accept: application/json, Host: oauth.platform.intuit.com, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I have created a simple console app in C#, I need to request access token without using SDK. I have managed to launch a URL to request code. I get code but trying to call the access_token endpoint is a challenge. I need help on how I can get access_token and refresh_token. Attached is the screenshot of codes having all the request details and the endpoint I used as follows.

Posting
Endpoint used: https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer

Parameters:[enter image description here][1]
code,=[codeReceived] grant_type = authorization_code and redirect_uri = [RedirectUrl]

Headers:
Authorization: Basic [Base64EncodedBytes], Accept: application/json, Host: oauth.platform.intuit.com, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

This is the Client Class I've created:

```
   public class RestClient
{     
    public string ClientID;
    public string ClientSecret;
    public string RedirectUrl = "https://devices.pythonanywhere.com/";
    public string Environment = "sandbox";

    
    private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string Url, string code, string ClientId, string ClientSecret)
    {
        var stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{ClientId}:{ClientSecret}");
        var encodedBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(stringBytes);
        

        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Url);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        
        query["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";
        query["code"] = $"{code}";
        query["redirect_uri"] = $"{RedirectUrl}";
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        Url = uriBuilder.ToString();

        var DecodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Url);

        Console.WriteLine(encodedBytes);
        
        HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, DecodedUrl);

        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {encodedBytes}");
        request.Headers.Add("Host", "oauth.platform.intuit.com");
        request.Content = new StringContent("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        using HttpClient client = new();
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
        return body.Result;
    }

    public string GetTokens(string Url, string code, string ClientId, string ClientSecret)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = GetAccessTokenAsync(Url, code, ClientId, ClientSecret).Result;

            if (response.Length>0)
            {
                return "There is data";
            }

            return "No data";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

    }

}
```

and this here is where I'm calling it

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.ClientID = "AB8EMz5arbI**************************************";
        client.ClientSecret = "4y4vsz*********************************";

        var OauthUrl = "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer";
        var code = "AB11644908535RgJ**************************";
        Console.WriteLine($"Response: {client.GetTokens(OauthUrl, code, client.ClientID, client.ClientSecret)}");

    }
}
```

Comment: would be good if you provide details on Auth server "oauth.platform.intuit.com". The Auth server usually has several endpoints
    {
      "issuer": "https://example.com/",
      "authorization_endpoint": "https://example.com/authorize",
      "token_endpoint": "https://example.com/token",
      "userinfo_endpoint": "https://example.com/userinfo",
      "jwks_uri": "https://example.com/.well-known/jwks.json",
      "scopes_supported": [
        "pets_read",
        "pets_write",
        "admin"
      ],
      ....
    }

Comment: I'm using token_endpoint https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth1/tokens/bearer

Comment: do you have the discovery(https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/discovery.html) endpoint? something like - https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth1/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: I have created a token exchange/refresh token flow without the use of openid config endpoint and QB SDK, manually. is that something you can use? so I put it as response.

Comment: You can put it here. It will also help me as that is what I'm about to do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a mistake in my C# code. Here is the working code that I used in GetAccessTokenAsync:

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string Url, string code, string ClientId, string ClientSecret)
    {
        var stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{ClientId}:{ClientSecret}");
        var encodedBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(stringBytes);
       
        HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, Url);

        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {encodedBytes}");

        var contentList = new List<string>();
        contentList.Add("grant_type=authorization_code");
        contentList.Add($"code={code}");
        contentList.Add($"redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}");
        request.Content = new StringContent(string.Join("&", contentList));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


        using HttpClient client = new();
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
        return body.Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate reviving old threads, but your answer helped me a lot. I had to change it a little bit to accept the refresh token rather than authorization code and thought I would post it here. I banged my head around for quite some time trying to figure this out without any useful documentation that I could find on the matter. I hope it helps someone in the same way that your code has helped me. Thanks!

```
public async Task<string> RefreshAccessToken(string Url, string RefreshToken, string ClientId, string ClientSecret)
    {
        var stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{ClientID}:{ClientSecret}");
        var encodedBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(stringBytes);

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Url);

        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {encodedBytes}");

        var contentList = new List<string>();
        contentList.Add("grant_type=refresh_token");
        contentList.Add($"refresh_token={RefreshToken}");
        request.Content = new StringContent(string.Join("&", contentList));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return body.Result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, I find that something like this works too.  Using RestSharp..

```
    public string RefreshAccessToken()
    {
        try
        {
            var stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{strClientID}:{strClientSecret}");
            var encodedBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(stringBytes);

            var client = new RestClient("https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer");
            client.UseJson();
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Basic {encodedBytes}");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
            request.AddParameter("refresh_token", CurrentRefreshToken);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            return response.Content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteError("RefreshAccessToken() - " + ex.Message);
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```